# Mutable NamedTuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I'm looking for a good struct pattern in python. The `NamedTuple` class constructor is *almost* what I want. Consider the following:

```py
class MyStruct(NamedTuple):
  prop1: str
  prop2: str
  prop3: Optional[str] = "prop3" # should allow default values
  prop4: Optional[str] = "prop4"
  ...

# allow this
struct = MyStruct(prop1="prop1", prop2="prop2")

# allow this (order agnostic)
struct = MyStruct(prop2="prop2", prop1="prop1")

# allow this (supply value to optional properties)
struct = MyStruct(prop1="prop1", prop2="prop2", prop3="hello")

# allow this (access via . syntax)
print(struct.prop3)

# allow this (mutate properties)
struct.prop2 = "hello!"

# don't allow this (missing required properties, prop1 and prop2)
struct = MyStruct()
```

`NamedTuple` does everything except the mutability piece. I'm looking for something similar to a `Namespace` with type hints. I looked at `TypedDict` as well, but don't like that you can't access properties with `struct.prop1`, but instead must use `struct["prop1"]`. I also need to be able to supply default values when the struct is instantiated.

I thought about just a regular class as well, but my object may have many properties (20-30), and the order in which properties are supplied to the constructor should not matter.

I also want type hinting in my editor.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Dataclasses! https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: Of course it's immutable, since it's just like tuples except the elements are named.

Comment: what's wrong wth a regular class (a dataclass is just a regular class, btw, one created by a the `dataclasses.dataclass` code generator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@dataclass`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class MyStruct:
    prop1: str
    prop2: str
    prop3: Optional[str] = "prop3"
    prop4: Optional[str] = "prop4"
```

Comment: The OP says they don't want the order of arguments to matter, with the implication that they will always use keyword arguments, so you might want to use `@dataclass(kw_only=True)` to enforce that (though this will require Python 3.10 or later).

Comment: One small note:
If you want it to be as similar to a C struct / a NamedTuple as possible, consider defining `__slots__` on your dataclass, too, to make it impossible to add more fileds and lower memory usage. For even more control, consider using the `attrs` package, this would also allow the non-order for python versions below 3.10.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If dataclass doesn't satisfy your requirements, try [recordclass](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/), literally a mutable named tuple.